# Track branches with git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm needing to use the git submodules so that my parent repository can track changes that occur in specific branches. I have a project with testing, beta and production branches. Both my parent and child repositories will need to have testing, beta, and production (main) branches.

Thanks if anyone can suggest me a solution to this.

Comment: Your repositories can already have all these branches. What was the problem?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use different branches of the submodule with different branches of the parent repo? If so, then the answer is yes. Just go into the submodule directory and checkout the branch you want (testing, beta, and production) then commit the submodule version to the parent repo.

Comment: It's a little confusing to understand at first. So if a file is modified on the testing branch in the child repository, won't that change automatically reflect on the submodule's testing branch?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

At a low level, Git fundamentally works by *hash IDs*, not by branch names.  Hash IDs are large, ugly, random-looking, and impossible for *humans* to remember.  But they're easy and convenient for *Git*, a computer program, to remember and work with, and so that's what it does.

When we (humans) use Git, we tend to like to use branch names to hide the fact that Git is really using hash IDs.  The submodule support in Git, however, mostly refuses to go along with this.  (I'll come back to the word *mostly* in a moment.)  Each submodule is being controlled by computer-program, so there's no *need* for branch names here, and Git simply doesn't bother.

Note that a submodule is really just another Git repository.  The only thing that makes it special—that makes it a submodule in the first place—is that some Git software keeps coming over to the submodule Git repository and running:

```
git switch --detach <hash>
```

(or the equivalent with `git checkout`), putting the submodule into *detached HEAD* mode at a specified commit hash ID.  The "controlling Git", which we call the *superproject*, reads these hash IDs out of data stored inside commits you make (on branches, if you work in the usual way) *in* the superproject.  You don't have to view these hash IDs, just as you don't have to view the hash IDs of each of your commits *in* the superproject.

So: it is the *superproject Git* (the commands you run in the superproject repository) that is doing the detached-head thing in the submodule.  You run `git switch` in the superproject, then you run `git submodule update` in the superproject—or you set "recursive" mode on and just run `git switch` in the superproject and it does the `git submodule update` for you—and the superproject forces the submodule into detached-HEAD mode.  The submodule therefore never sees or bothers with any branch names at all.  The hash ID that the superproject Git uses here comes from an entity that Git calls a *gitlink*.

The model you should have in mind is that any commits you *want* in the submodule simply appear, magically, maybe out of nowhere.  For instance, perhaps you're using Fred's Library of Wonderful Wonders as a submodule.  Fred makes a new release and you'd like to pick it up, so you:

1. `cd library/fred` to enter the submodule;
2. `git fetch origin` to call up Fred's repository and get version 2.0;
3. `git switch --detach v2.0` to get Fred's version-2.0;
4. `cd ../..` back to your own project;
5. edit your project if/as needed to make use of the new whizzy features;
6. run `git add library/fred` to update the *gitlink* for the next commit;
7. run `git add` as needed on your own files (you can do this before, during, or after step 6); and
8. run `git commit` to make a new commit in your superproject.

The new commit has a new gitlink, which records the new (correct) hash ID for Version 2.0 in `library/fred`.  Note how no *branch names* have been used anywhere in this process.

Sometimes, of course, you *would* like to use a branch name: instead of *tag* `v2.0`, you want to pick up Fred's latest commit on his `main`.  To do *that*, you change step 3 to read:

```
git switch --detach origin/main
```

Again, no *branch names on your end* are being used, but this time you did use `origin/main`: your remote-tracking name for Fred's `main`.

#### This is the one place that branch name support exists in submodules

In the above, you had to run:

```
(cd library/fred && git fetch origin && git switch --detach origin/main)
```

or whatever branch name you wanted.  By setting a branch for a submodule, you can make:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

do the above sequence of commands for you.  **That's all it does.**  There is no magic here.  Given how little actual value this adds, I personally recommend that you just use your own literal parenthesized sub-command here, if only to remind yourself of how poor the submodule support is in Git.

#### If your goal is to do your own work in submodules ...

If you intend to do *your own* commits in a submodule, the way Git's submodules work becomes more painful.  What you end up doing is replacing the eight-step sequence above with:

```
cd library/mine
git checkout develop
... do development work ...
... test, etc., as needed ...
git commit
git push <options>
cd ../..
git add library/mine
git commit             # make new gitlink
git push <options>
```

But this assumes that everything always works the first time, which is rarely true in the real world.  You end up having to go back and forth between submodule and superproject, and every once in a while you discover that the superproject Git has re-detached your submodule's HEAD.  It's always predictable when this will happen, and afterwards you go *oh right* and fix it, but in practice it's painful and leads to the nickname of *sob*-modules.

Submodules *do* work.  Just know what kind of experience you're setting yourself up for.

Comment: My sincere thanks. I understand exactly how it works and what I need to do for my use case.